# Cant save/update property value in Active Directory

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory

I am trying to save/update the property `Surname` in Active Directory. It works fine with the `UserPrincipal` class, but I want to use `DirectoryEntry`.

The `DirectoryEntry` saving does also work but not with the surname. Somehow I always get the exception:

> The directory service attribute or value of the specified directory service is not available.

Code:

```
// This part works fine
var principalUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain),IdentityType.SamAccountName, "FirstName.LastName");
principalUser.Surname = "LastName";
principalUser.Save();

// Works not with surname
DirectoryEntry userEntry = (DirectoryEntry)principalUser.GetUnderlyingObject();
userEntry.Properties["surname"].Value = "LastName";
userEntry.CommitChanges(); // --> Exception been thrown here
```

What does Microsoft do differently when saving / updating a value in the `UserPrincipal` class?

I tried to refresh the cache, but it doesn't work for me:

```
userEntry.RefreshCache(new string[] { "surname" });
```

**edit:**

Thanks to marc_s we could solve it. Be shure to always search for the Ldap-Display-Name when you messing with properties in LDAP.
In my case https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679872(v=vs.85).aspx I didnt see that the Ldap-Dipslay-Name of the attribut Surname is **"sn"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LDAP attribute name for "surname" is `sn` - try this:

```
DirectoryEntry userEntry = (DirectoryEntry)principalUser.GetUnderlyingObject();
userEntry.Properties["sn"].Value = "LastName";
userEntry.CommitChanges();
```

See [Richard Mueller's web site](http://www.rlmueller.net/UserAttributes.htm) for very comprehensive lists and Excel sheets with all the relevant LDAP attributes, their names and other properties

Comment: Saved my day :). I just rechecked the msdn documentation, I didnt see that the surname its Ldap-Display-Name is "sn"                                                                                         https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679872(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: For ***CN: Address*** the `Ldap-Display-Name` is **streetAddress**.

For ***CN: Street-Address*** the `Ldap-Display-Name` is **street**.